# Difference between 少し{すこし} and 少ない{すくない}

Tags: word-choice, words, usage

I know 少し{すこし} and 少ない{すくない} both as 'few', but what's the difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those two words do not assume the same roles. 少{すこ}し is an adverb and 少{すく}ない is an i-adjective. So basically, 少し will modify a verb whereas 少ない will tell that there is not much of something.

Some examples.

> - 友達｛ともだち｝が少ない。I don't have a lot of friends.
> - 時間｛じかん｝が少なくなった。There is not much time left. (lit. Time has become rarer.)
> - Aさん：日本語｛にほんご｝話｛はな｝せるかい。Bさん：少しだけ（話せる）。(A: Can you speak Japanese? B: Just a bit.)
> - 納豆{なっとう}を少し食｛た｝べました。I ate a bit/some of nattou (but not much of it).